# Fonts changes between computers, unreadable

Tags: fonts, xetex, formatting

I'm using TexMaker on OS X, compiling with Xetex, and I'm having some fonts issues. Depending on the computer I look at the pdf file I get the either the correct fonts or not, see in the image below:

[image: Good fonts][image]

I've tried saving the fonts within the file (on a Mac simply by opening with 'Preview' and saving over), I've tried verifying wether the file is corrupted, but it is not... I have no idea what to do, but I would not like to change fonts. Any idea? This is the part of the header I believe is most important for this problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openbib,fleqn,reqno]{book}  %A5
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}  % Math package of AMS 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}           % use \textsubscript{}

% XeLaTeX
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}      % For Russian
\newfontfamily\russianfont{Cambria}
\usepackage{xeCJK}              % For Chinese/Japanese/Korean
\setCJKmainfont{MS Mincho}      % for \rmfamily
\setCJKsansfont{MS Gothic}      % for \sffamily
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Adobe Devanagari}  %\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
```

Thanks in advance,
Jon

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) While code samples are useful, it is in most situations best to make them into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). In your case, it simply means adding the `\begin{document}`, some text showing the issue (have a look at packages such as `lipsum` if you don't want to include actual text), and `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jon If you're using `TeXShop` on your Mac be careful with the encoding. That editor by default loads an encoding available and readable only for Mac. You need to change it to `Latin1`, `utf8` or the encoding you use or try with another editor.

Comment: The output from `pdffonts <filename>.pdf` would be useful.

Comment: To clarify, are you compiling the file on different computers or are you viewing an already created PDF on different computers? If the former, do you have the same fonts installed on both?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The problem is that the same pdf file, compiled on my mac, was viewed differently depending on the pdf reader and the OS used. Finally I "printed" with adobe a new pdf, and **it solved my problem**, even though I have know lost all text capabilities and hyperlinking (from TOC). I am sure the fonts are included in the pdf, I could check that with acrobat. **The problem remains a mystery to me...**